# Type with $X\rightarrow X\cong X + 1$

Tags: type-theory

In the article [Voevodsky’s Univalence Axiom in Homotopy Type Theory](http://www.ams.org/notices/201309/rnoti-p1164.pdf), an example is given of how types are not like sets: the existence of a nontrivial (nonzero) type $X$ such that  $X\rightarrow X\cong X + 1$. However, I am unable to find this counterexample in the references in the article. Does anyone know this example? Is it a special case of some more general universal property, like maybe a type $X$ with $Y\rightarrow X \cong Y +1$ for all $Y$?

Comment: The following should morally be an example, but I don't know how to make it precise (I read some things about it once but the details were way more complicated than I expected). Find a topos, something like a topos of computable functions, where $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ consists of the computable functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. These can be computably enumerated, so $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ should be computably in bijection with $\mathbb{N} + 1$.

Comment: (I think the reason the details were more complicated than I expected is the following. The above line of reasoning suggests that $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ should even be computably in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$. But if this is the case then the Lawvere fixed point theorem implies that every computable function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ has a fixed point, which is clearly false. I think some fiddling around with partial functions is necessary to fix this. Probably Andrej Bauer knows the real story here.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not ready to venture into homotopy type theory yet, but there is an example in topos theory, which might be transportable into the context you want.  In the object-classifier topos, the generic object $U$ satisfies $U^U\cong U+1$.  This is Example 1 in an old paper of mine, "Functions on universal algebras" [J. Pure Appl. Alg. 42 (1986) 25-28].

Comment: As I understand it, homotopy type theory is supposed to be the syntax of e.g. $(\infty, 1)$-topoi and so in particular should be interpretable in any ordinary topos.